# MYSQL Statement - Pulling from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database.  Each has three things in it:  an identifier which is just a  auto generated number, a text field and an integer field.  The data in the text field (let's call it `Names`) is the exact same in both tables.  Only the numbers fields are different.  I need the statements to compare the two sets of number fields, and list every name where the number is not zero in either table.  I also need it to add the two numbers together in the fields and and make a separate column with the combined value and list the names by order of that values from highest value to lowest.

This is as far as I have gotten and now I am stuck, I am very new to SQL

```
SELECT tableone.names
FROM tableone, tabletwo
WHERE (tableone.numbers > 0) AND (tabletwo.numbers > 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
 tableone.names,
 tableone.numbers + tabletwo.numbers AS numbers_sum
FROM tableone
LEFT JOIN tabletwo USING (names)
WHERE (tableone.numbers > 0)
 AND (tabletwo.numbers > 0)
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

update, tested sql:

```
USE test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableone (
  names TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  numbers INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (names(100))
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabletwo (
  names TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  numbers INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (names(100))
);

INSERT INTO tableone SELECT 'a', RAND();
INSERT INTO tableone SELECT 'b', RAND();
INSERT INTO tableone SELECT 'c', RAND();
INSERT INTO tableone SELECT 'd', RAND();
INSERT INTO tabletwo SELECT names, RAND() FROM tableone;

SELECT
 tableone.names,
 tableone.numbers + tabletwo.numbers AS numbers_sum
FROM tableone
LEFT JOIN tabletwo USING (names)
WHERE (tableone.numbers > 0)
 AND (tabletwo.numbers > 0)
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

output:

```
+-------+-------------+
| names | numbers_sum |
+-------+-------------+
| b     |           2 |
| d     |           2 |
+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: When I try that, it says I have a syntax error in the FROM clause?

Comment: i tested the sql i wrote, and it worked, can it me a misspeled table name at your server?

Comment: it keeps highlighting the (names) and saying there is an error in the from clause.. but the name is correct in the table.. I dont understand it at all

Comment: whats the table name? is it one of the mysql keywords? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html